# SSRS BIDS 2008 R2 pie chart data labels overlapping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, bids, pie-chart

[image: image1][image: image2]

As seen in image, the data labels are overlapping and making the data difficult to read. Anybody know how to sort this?

- Have now updated the question as I have changed the PieLabelStyle to Outside and in the picture you can see in the design view above it acknowledges this however when I preview the chart it remains on the inside! (See image 3 link below)

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFgJr.jpg)

Comment: I would advice you not to use pie charts at all. 3d pie charts are even worse, use barcharts instead.

Comment: +1 to @jrara for giving some good data visualization advice. More developers need to be aware of info design principals.

Comment: +1 SQL_Surfer. My pie charts always look terrible. It looks like Jamie has a solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technet has [a nice piece](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220583.aspx) on this:

The secret is in the Properties pane under the Custom Attributes section:
[image: Series Custom Attributes Screenshot]

Comment: Have now done this however the pie chart % remains on the inside in the preview screen, see updated question/screenshots

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to sort the pie chart between small and big pieces. I posted a script that helps with this issue:
http://williameduardo.com/development/ssrs/pie-chart-series-label-overlapping-in-ssrs/