# SSRS 3.0 pie chart data label position

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

With SSRS 3.0 I have found that several of the charting property attributes are expressed as percentages relative to the space allowed. Specifically, with 'inside' pie chart data labels, it appears that the labels are auto-positioned 50% between the center of the circle and the edge. Is there any way to move these data labels outward to, say, 75%? The chart series.label.position property will accept an expression but any ideas of the syntax? Is what I'm driving at even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is possible to specify where they go inside of the chart. I would suggest moving them to the outside: [SSRS BIDS 2008 R2 pie chart data labels overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054152/ssrs-bids-2008-r2-pie-chart-data-labels-overlapping)